# what is the difference object database systems?

Tags: database, object, object-oriented-database, object-relationships

Comparison of object database management systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

and

Comparison of object-relational database management systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object-relational_database_management_systems

and

Comparison of object-relational mapping software: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object-relational_mapping_software

Are they all the same?
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**object database management systems**: 
A database management system (DBMS) that stores Objects.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

**object-relational database management systems**: 
Like a relational DBMS but it can store objects and has object-oriented capabilities (like inheretence).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database

and

**object-relational mapping software**: 
A software interface, that provides functions to store Objects of an OO language into a relational DBMS (tables)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping